# Where does The Oil Blue save game progress?

Tags: the-oil-blue

In what location on the filesystem does [The Oil Blue](http://www.desura.com/games/the-oil-blue) store your progress through the game when you save in game?

I have found something in the following folder, but I am not sure what it is:

> C:\Users\Wok\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files
>   (x86)\Desura\Common\The Oil Blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It is saved in the datafiles folder, secretly named island1outline.gsmpr thru island6outline."

Reference: [Vertigo Gaming Forum](http://www.vertigogaming.net/newboards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4476).